# how to find which method is causing the error during parallel ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using $.when to make parallel ajax call to webapi controller and it works perfectly fine. The structure is given below,

```
$.when(GetDataFromMethodA(),GetDataFromMethodB(),GetDataFromMethodC())
 .done(function (responseFromMethodA,responseFromMethodB, responseFromMethodC) {         
               if (responseFromMethodA != null) {
                   //do some action
               }

               if (responseFromMethodB != null) {
                   //do some action
               }

              if (responseFromMethodC != null) {
                   //do some action
               }

            }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {               
              //which method raised the exception?
            });
```

Methods:

```
function GetDataFromMethodA() {

    var Request = {};
    Request.Code = name.find(':selected').val();

    return $.ajax({
        url: 'api/Data/GetCurrentView',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: Request
    });
}
```

similarly, I have method B and C.

**QUESTION:**

There are situations where any one of the method fails and based on the failing method, I need to display appropriate message to the user. When anyone of the method fails, the exception is caught in the 'fail' section. But, how to find which method raised the exception?

Comment: if i'm reading your code right, then you get the failing `xhr` as first parameter to `fail`. wouldn't this object contain details that would help identify which one went wrong?

Comment: @amenthes, thanks for the direction. Let me look at the xhr object.

Comment: @downvoter, please provide the reason for downvoting this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `always` instead of `done`, you can inspect whether the request succeeded with `isResolved()` or `isRejected()`, for instance:

```
$.when(GetDataFromMethodA(),GetDataFromMethodB(),GetDataFromMethodC())
 .always(function (responseFromMethodA,responseFromMethodB, responseFromMethodC) { 
   if(responseFromMethodA.isRejected()) { 
     console.log('A did not work!'); 
   }
   if(responseFromMethodB.isRejected()) {
     console.log('B did not work!'); 
   }
   // ...etc.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. Let me try that as well.